# jQuery deferred/promise with SPService library

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, spservices

I'm trying to get my promise item from SPService SPGetListItemsJson. The issue is that when SPGetListItemsJson is invoked and when requestPromise is done and the deferred is resolve, I would expect the data to pass into my anonymously function in populateDropDownControlWithList but its undefined.

```
   function populateDropDownControlWithList(option, control, addSelectValue)
    {
        if (typeof (addSelectValue) === 'undefined')
        {
            addSelectValue = false;
        }

        var selectedIndex = control.val() ? control.val() : -1;    
        if (addSelectValue)
        {
            control.append('<option value=-1>Select an Option</option>');
        }

        var request = SPGetListItemsJson(option);
        request.done(function (data) // Expect the json object here but it is undefined
        {
            $.each(data, function () 
            {
                controlappend('<option value=' + this.Id + '>' + this.Title + '</option>');
            });
        });
    }

    function SPGetListItemsJson(option)
    {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var requestsPromise = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
            listName: option.Name,
            CAMLQuery: option.Query,
            CAMLViewFields: option.View,
            mappingOverrides: option.Mapping,
            debug: option.Debug,
            async: option.async
        });

        requestsPromise.done(function ()
        {
            deferred.resolveWith(this.data); // Verified this.data is populated with the correct result
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the following changes I was able to get it to work now.  I'm posting it incase someone finds this useful.

```
request.done(function ()
{
    $.each(this, function () 
    {
        control.append('<option value=' + this.ID + '>' + this.Title + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done it:

```
function getListOne() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "ListOne",
        completefunc: function(data, status) {
            console.log("first is done");
            if (status == "success") {
                //do stuff
                dfd.resolve("");
            } else {
                dfd.reject();
            }
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

function getListTwo() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "ListTwo",
        completefunc: function(data, status) {
            console.log("second is done");
            if (status == "success") {
                //do stuff
                dfd.resolve("");
            } else {
                dfd.reject();
            }
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
$.when(getListOne(), getListTwo()).then(function() {
    console.log("both are done");
});
```

It is easier to prove that it is working with 2 lists and the console logs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson()` returns a promise?

The SPServices documentation is ambiguous. It says that the method returns a JavaScript (plain) object but then goes on to give an example saying `var traineePromise = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({...})` and continues with `$.when(traineePromise).done(...)` .

Therefore, it would be prudent to write your `SPGetListItemsJson()` as follows :

```
function SPGetListItemsJson(option) {
    var obj = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
        listName: option.Name,
        CAMLQuery: option.Query,
        CAMLViewFields: option.View,
        mappingOverrides: option.Mapping,
        debug: option.Debug,
        async: option.async
    });
    return $.when(obj).then(function () {
        return this.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes SPGetListItemsJson() returns a promise.